# changing jhipster-registry port

Tags: microservices, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I've looked over most of the documentation provided, couldn't find an absolute answer about changing ***jhipster-registry*** port, it's default is **8761**, but when I try to chnage it's port through ***YAML*** config file it gets indeed working in that port but both the gateway and microservice cannot be found by the registry. am i doing anything wrong ? is ***jhipster-registry*** bound to remain intact when it comes to port manipulation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must change port in `spring.cloud.config.uri` in all application's bootstrap*.yml so they can retrieve their config from the registry and also change it in `eureka.client.defaultZone` in `application.yml` in jhipster-registry's `central-config` folder if you use file system backend or in git repo if you use git backend.

This is because the registry is both a Spring Cloud Config server and an Eureka server. In JHipster's setup, the applications first connect to the config server, retrieve their config which indicate the URL of the Eureka server. As this is a common config for all apps, it's set in application*.yml in config server.

Please read also the jhipster-registry doc: https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/

Comment: I did as you requested, It actually works , but the  jhipster-registry log keeps getting me this error : 
 Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8943/eureka/

Comment: I think I've mistakenly changed defaultZone credentials in url which caused this issue, replaced in the application.yml the ${jhipster.registry.password} by ${spring.security.user.password:admin} and change eureka's defaultZone in all applications and now it's working fine, thanks !